# Xcode: project navigator, difference between Yellow folder and blue folder

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to know the difference between a blue folder and a yellow folder in Xcode.

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487760/what-is-a-blue-folder-in-xcode) but doesn't clarify my doubts!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yellow folders are "Groups", they are not actual folders but references to folders/files. They exist only to organize your project in Xcode. Blue folders are actual folders existent in the file system.

Blue folders give you the benefit of not having to "Add File" everytime something new lands in the folder i.e. an image. However, you should still mostly use groups (aka yellow folders) because it gives you more control on what will be bundled with your app (think of hidden files in the folder/versioning files). Also, sometimes blue folders can mess up your file hierarchy in your bundle, ie. causing the splash screen to malfunction.
There are only a few cases where you would use blue folders, like a "content" folder, where anything in the folder should be packed with the bundle (as Mark Szymczyk commented, images or videos). If you're not sure, stick with yellow folders.

Comment: Ok. Perfect answer ! But when I should use one rather than other ?

Comment: And how can I create a blue hierarchy ?

Comment: @Fry, Add a folder to your project by choosing File > Add Files to ProjectName. Select the Create folder references for any added folders radio button in the Open panel. Blue folders are for files you wouldn't directly access in Xcode, such as sound and image files. For folders of source code files you should use yellow folders instead of blue.

Comment: @Fry, additionally to Mark Szymczyk's explanation, I updated the answer to hopefully give you a better idea on what to use.

Comment: When I add a group within the Xcode project navigator and look in finder a new folder is created (using Xcode 10.3)

Answer (score 2):

Yellow folder should be links (group, act as a folder, but if you check in Finder, there are not, like a Playlist in iTunes), and blues ones are « physical » (as folder in Finder).