# Bridging File Not Found

Tags: objective-c, swift

The bridging file is added, but keeps showing the error.

My Bridging Header File is correctly setup because the other imports are successful.

[image]

Comment: You sure that file is in your project and is selected for your target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) to handle external frameworks. [Here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SlackTextViewController) is SlackTextViewController. If you still want to use copied version, make sure you add the files to your project. Try copying the files to your project folder using Finder and then use Xcode File -> Add files to "YOUR_PROJECT"

Comment: I tried that. Still is only a reference. Any way to specify where the file is?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346247/xcode-project-navigator-difference-between-yellow-folder-and-blue-folder 
Don't add the entire folder, add the files and then group them